# Styled text using word styles, e.g. shading, boxes, fonts, etc

Tags: microsoft-word, xml

In Word 2003 you could create (and retain) a document with a style from an XML template after XSLT translation.

I think it was called Microsoft document ML (MML).  Is there anything today that could do the same thing?

It seems Microsoft got into a lawsuit about patents with a Canadian company and I am unable to find an equivalent feature today.

Comment: What version of Microsoft Word are you using now?